# C++ Boost Unit Test: How to manually finish unit test with success?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, networking, boost, boost-asio

Currently I'm coding a network lib based on Boost asio.
I want to automatically test my lib with a kind of loopback echo test.
The problem is, that the server is running continuously thus the test never ends.
My idea is to do some EQUAL tests with response data and to manually stop the unit test with success. If a timeout occurs otherwise, the test should stop with fail (I know, it's more an integration test as an unit test)...
Is there a Boost Unit Test macro to manually stop the test with success?

Thanks!

Comment: Manually? You mean from the "outside" by giving some command to the test process?

Comment: I want to stop from inside the BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE / function.

Comment: Could you post some (pseudo) code of your test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just leave the test function, that will count as success. If you want to explicitly "set" the result, you can use `BOOST_CHECK(true)` for success and or `BOOST_CHECK(false)` for failure. There are variants of these macros with an additional message to be printed on failure (`BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE`).

The test framework itself is single threaded and the individual tests run one after the other. Each test function has to end by either an explicit `return` statement or execution "falling off the end".

If you call a function that does not return by itself but needs some trigger to do so, you need to somehow schedule this trigger before calling the function. This might require starting a thread, waiting there for a certain time and then sending the trigger to cause the blocking function to return.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! What do you mean with "leave"? If I return from my test case, nothing happens and timeout occurs.

Comment: Hm, that should not be the case. Are there multiple threads involved?
Where does the timeout occur? In the boost test framework or your component under test?

Comment: Or are you using the `timeout` decorator (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/timeout.html)?

Comment: Hi Marvin, sorry for my late reply. You're correct. It was a error with multithreading. I simply stopped the io_service inside the thread if all tests were successful. Thanks a lot!